# Linux vs. Unix file wildcards

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm looking to get a list of files in a directory in Linux starting with a capital letter.  In Unix, it's a simple

ls [A-Z]*

In Linux, though, I'm seeing matches that don't seem to be case-sensitive:

```
=> ls
A.txt  b.txt  B.txt  c.txt  C.txt

=> ls [A]*
A.txt

=> ls [AB]*
A.txt  B.txt

=> ls [ABC]*
A.txt  B.txt  C.txt
```

=> ls [A-C]*
    A.txt  b.txt  B.txt  c.txt  C.txt

```
=> ls [b]*
b.txt
```

=> ls [a-c]*
    A.txt  b.txt  B.txt  c.txt

Running the same commands on the Unix side work as I'd expect.  Is this the way Linux has always behaved?  It's easy enough to work around this with awk, so I'm not looking for a solution in that way, but I'm wondering if I just never noticed this before.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't see anything special in your outputs... Please clarify (at least command and outputs seems to be mixed at some point). Also note that it is not a matter of OS (Linux vs Unix vs...) but a matter of shell variant and configuration.

Comment: Right, I was expecting [A-C} to not include b or c, but per the answers, it's the impact of environment variables (as you point out, not Linux vs. Unix).

Answer (score 7):

The result depends on different shell options, particularly: nocasematch nocaseglob
And also LC_COLLATE variable (used in sort, [-], etc.)

```
$ shopt extglob nocasematch nocaseglob
extglob         off
nocasematch     off
nocaseglob      off


$ printf "%s\n" a A b B c C | sort
a
A
b
B
c
C
```

So [A-C] range contains b and c, but not a, also [a-c] should contain A but not C.

```
$ printf "%s\n" a A b B c C | LC_COLLATE=C sort
A
B
C
a
b
c
```

gives a different result.

```
$ LC_COLLATE=C ls [A-C]*
```

Should return expected result, this syntax sets the variable only for the new process execution (ls), but not in current shell process.

EDIT: thanks to comment, previous command is wrong because the expansion is processed before the LC_COLLATE be set, the simplest is to split into two commands.

```
$ export LC_COLLATE=C
$ ls [A-C]*
```

Comment: In the example of `LC_COLLATE=C ls [A-C]*`, `LC_COLLATE` is set for the execution of `ls` -- but the glob is expanded **before** that execution takes place. This is also why `s=hello echo $s` doesn't work as folks expect.